# VBA: How to keep my csv format when transferring excel data to it?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a csv file that I have separated based on commas.  I'm using a csv file because I'm using it as a "master" file to hold a lot of information but I would prefer columns rather than having it separated by commas.

So the code I need is to be able to run a macro that will take cells from my "copy" excel workbook, and move append it to where the new blank cells begin at the bottom of my "master" csv file.

For example:

```
 A        B       C
Week     Time     Month
3        09:03    March
```

My Master.csv will have the same column headings and I will want to continually update the Master.csv when I get new info from my copy.xlsx which is updated weekly.

```
Sub move2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant

'Open workbooks
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wra\Desktop\macro test\copy")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wra\Desktop\macro test\Master.csv")

'Store value in variable
vals = x.Sheets("copy").Range("A5").Value

'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
y.Sheets("Master").Range("A3").Value = vals

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

I know this code doesn't do what I want full yet (only takes one value and adds it to a specific place in the master.csv, but it's a start I guess.

The thing is, when I run this macro, information from my copy.xlsx is moved to the Master.csv, BUT the master.csv gets reformatted from columns to text.

So after the macro is run it looks like the following:

```
A
Week,Time,Month
3,09:03,March
```

All the data goes back to one column and the Text to Columns function I used before hand is removed.

How can I prevent this from happening? And if anyone can help with the next part of code (where I want it to append to the bottom of my master.csv data, that would be awesome.

Hope this was clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: when opening the csv file, try the `Workbooks.OpenText` method, instead of `Workbooks.Open`?

Comment: If you place comma-separate values in a single cell in a CSV file opened in Excel, when you save that file it's going to keep those values in that one cell (by wrapping the value in quotes, which you'll see if you open your CSV file in notepad).  If you want the values to be in separate "columns" in your CSV then you need to place each value in a separate cell in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467082/david-zemens) said, use `Workbooks.OpenText` to ensure your master file is opened correctly, e.g.:

```
Set y = Workbooks.OpenText("C:\Users\wra\Desktop\macro test\Master.csv", DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True)
```

To append to the bottom of the master file, you will need to find the last row in the file, and input your data below that. There are many ways to find the last row in Excel, but one method is to do the following:

```
myLastRow = y.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

which finds the last row in in the first column of the "Master" sheet. The new data could then be copied in like so:

```
y.Sheets("Master").Cells(myLastRow + 1, 1).Resize(number_rows, number_cols).Value = vals
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Worked great! Extremely new to VBA and that helped me out a lot.  I just had to use Call Workbooks.OpenText and then Set the variable to the ActiveWorkbook because it didn't let me do it directly.  Thanks again!